# why this doesn't add a count to my current item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a shopping cart in where whenever the item is already in the cart and the add to cart button is clicked another time, the item's count is supposed to get added by one. And each time that button is clicked, it should get added to the cart the number of items.

I've tried performing this by finding the index of the item and if it exists, sum by one the counts of the item. But that's not working as the number is not getting summed.

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react'
import data from './data.js'
import useCountsContext from './context/useCountsContext.js'
var uniqid = require('uniqid');

function Shop({ data }) {
  const {count, setCount} = useContext(useCountsContext)
  const {item, setItem} = useContext(useCountsContext)

  const addCart = (productsId) => {
      setCount(count + 1)
      data.forEach((product) => {

        let findInd = item.findIndex((i) => i.id  === product.id);
        const exists = (findInd > -1);
       // Part where it is supposed to add if the item is already in the cart
       if (exists) {
         let newArry = [...item];
        let newObj = { ...newArry[findInd]};
        newObj.counts += 1
         setItem(newArry);

       }  else if (product.id === productsId) {
          setItem(item.concat(product))
        }
      })
  }

    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Shop</h1>
          <div className="div___shop">
          {data.map(({id, img, button}) => (
            <>
              <img className="img___shop" key={id} src={img}></img>
              <div key={id}>
                <button onClick={() => addCart(id)}>{button}</button>
              </div>
            </>
          ))}
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Shop
```

Here is the data file I have

```
import diCaprio from './img/diCaprio.jpg'
import steveJobs from './img/steveJobs.jpg'
import lips from './img/lips.jpg'
import buda from './img/buda.jpg'
import spaceDog from './img/spaceDog.jpg'
import astroNube from './img/astroNube.jpg'
import banksy from './img/Banksy.jpg'
import banksyDJ from './img/banksyDJ.jpg'
var uniqid = require('uniqid');


const data = [{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: steveJobs,
  homeImg: steveJobs,
  button: "add to cart",
  counts: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: diCaprio,
  homeImg: diCaprio,
  button: "add to cart",
  counts: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: lips,
  homeImg: lips,
  button: "add to cart",
  counts: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: buda,
  homeImg: buda,
  button: "add to cart",
  counts: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: spaceDog,
  button: "add to cart",
  counts: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img:astroNube,
  button: "add to cart",
  counts: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: banksy,
  button: "add to cart",
  counts: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img:banksyDJ,
  button: "add to cart",
  counts: 0
}
]

export default data;
```

Here is the useCountsContext code:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

const useCountsContext = createContext();

export default useCountsContext;
```

Comment: Please include the code defined in `useCountsContext`

Comment: it is just to create the context. Already edited with it

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mutating `newObj.counts` here:

```
let newObj = { ...newArry[findInd]};
newObj.counts += 1
```

Instead, use spread operator to change the value of `counts`. i.e.

```
mutated = { ...newObj, counts: newObj.count += 1 };
```

That being said, you don't need `let newArry = [...item];`, instead use `item.filter...` to find the `newObj` you want to act on.

Then after that, create a `newArry`, ensuring you add `mutated` to it and remove the `newObj`. But again, just make sure you don't mutate objects directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using this:

```
data.forEach((product) => {
  let findInd = item.findIndex((i) => i.id  === product.id);
  const exists = (findInd > -1);

  if (exists) {
    const targetObject = item[findInd]
    targetObject.counts += 1

    const newItems = [
      ...item.slice(0, findInd),
      targetObject, 
      ...item.slice(findInd + 1)
    ]
    setItem(newItems);
  }
```

You basically form new array with updated count and change the state by passing it to `setItem`.

In your case, you are copying one item from an array `let newObj = { ...newArry[findInd]}`, incrementing it by 1 but not updating `newArry` that is why count also is not updated.

**Update:**

I updated your code to make it more readable and fixed count bug (there was a problem somewhere in forEach function and productsId search). I also used useState hook instead of useContext

I reproduced the code below in CodeSandbox - everything works fine and counts as you wanted - [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-cherry-r27xn)

```
const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
const [item, setItem] = React.useState([])

const addCart = (productsId) => {
  setCount(count + 1)
  const index = item.findIndex((e) => e.id  === productsId);
  if (index === -1) {
    const newArr = [...item].concat(data.filter((e) => e.id === productsId))
    setItem(newArr)
  } else {
    const targetObject = item[index]
    targetObject.counts += 1

    const newItems = [
      ...item.slice(0, index),
      targetObject, 
      ...item.slice(index + 1)
    ]
    setItem(newItems);
  }
}
```

Comment: in this case each item gets updated once. But whenever another item is clicked, the first item also gets updated

Comment: @godtrianglefd pls check the post, I updated it

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing `useContext()` and `useState()`. I got rid of all context and replaced it with state. Take a look at what I did and see if it makes sense.

[Running code in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-cdn-bli0e)

```
function Shop() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  const addCart = (productsId) => {
      setCount(count + 1)

      let findInd = items.findIndex((i) => i.id  === productsId);
      const exists = (findInd > -1);

      // Part where it is supposed to add if the item is already in the cart
      if (exists) {
        const newArry = items.map(x => (x.id===productsId) ? {...x, counts: x.counts + 1} : x)
        setItems(newArry);
      }
      else {
        const product = data.find(x => x.id === productsId);
        
        setItems([...items, {...product, counts: 1}])
      }
  }

    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Shop</h1>
          <div className="div___shop">
               <h3>Total count: {count}</h3>
              <div>
                <h3>Cart items:</h3>
                <div style={{margin: '10px'}}>
                  {items.map(x => (
                    <div>item {x.id} image: {x.img} count: {x.counts}</div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
              {data.map(({id, img, button}) => (
              <>
 
                <div key={id}>
                  {`id: ${id} img: ${img} `}
                  <button onClick={() => addCart(id)}>{button}</button>
                </div>
              </>
          ))}
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```